# What is the bash shortcut to change to the previous directory?

Tags: bash, shell, cd-command

Sadly, I only learned about this last year by stumbling upon it randomly on the internet. I use it so infrequently that I always forget what it is by the time I need it again.

How do you change to your previous directory?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The shortcut is `-`

Try `cd -`

If you want to use this in your prompt, you have to refer to it with `~-`.

See the example:

```
[echox@kaffeesatz ~]$ cd /tmp
[echox@kaffeesatz tmp]$ ls
cron.iddS32  serverauth.CfIgeXuvka
[echox@kaffeesatz tmp]$ cd -
/home/echox
[echox@kaffeesatz ~]$ ls ~-
cron.iddS32  serverauth.CfIgeXuvka
```

Answer (score 25):

You might also want to look at `pushd` and `popd`, which create a stack of directories to remember where you were.

To use, `pushd <directory>` changes to `<directory>` and saves the previous directory.  To change back to this saved directory, use `popd`.

Answer (score 4):

As per the answer by @echox, you can indeed use `cd -` as the man page for `bash` explains:

> When  a    is used as the operand, this shall be equivalent to the command:
>
> ```
>                 cd "$OLDPWD" && pwd
> ```
>
> which changes to the previous working directory and then writes its name.

Note the changed-to directory is output by the inherent `pwd` in `cd -`. You may not want that output in a script. That's where the alternative becomes useful - just do

```
cd "$OLDPWD"
```

and you're done!