# How to go to the previous working directory in terminal?

Tags: shell, cd-command

In terminal, how can I define a key to go to the previous directory which I was in when changing directory with the `cd` command?

For example, I'm in `/opt/soft/bin` and I `cd` into `/etc/squid3` and I want to get back to the first directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the bash shortcut to change to the previous directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3284/what-is-the-bash-shortcut-to-change-to-the-previous-directory)

Answer (score 413, accepted):

You can use

```
cd -
```

or you could use

```
cd "$OLDPWD"
```

Comment: Any idea why the directory name is printed to the console when using "cd -" ?

Comment: Probably since the old shells didn't display the name of the current directory in the prompt, it was helpful to see the name of the directory when you typed `cd -`. For example when you type `cd /usr/local` you know that you are in `/usr/loal`, but when you type `cd -` you don't always remember from which directory you came from. So it saves you from typing `cd -; pwd`. But this is all speculation.

Comment: Or you can use aliasing: Set up alias as `alias -- -='cd -'` then use `-` (1 char) instead of `cd -` (4 char). Faster `:D`

Comment: I used a simple technique instead. Just added a new line character after "`cd -`" so now `cd -\n` takes me directly to the next directory

Comment: @ADTC : I added "Command + Left" key combination to go backwards in my iTerm Global Key Shortcuts. Faster and more related.

Comment: @Rajkiran sure why not? But that's client-dependent. Look my comment on Atari911's answer, where I bound F12 to the command. Server-side and even faster (just one key). Though I agree, it's not related - but who uses F12 for anything anyway?

Comment: How could I ever live without this?

Comment: Is there a way to reverse this command and go to the previous directory, where I just came from (to the directory where I just typed `cd -`)?

Comment: @AndréKuhlmann You can do `cd -` twice. Do `cd /; cd /usr;  cd -; cd -` you should be in `/usr`. But maybe I miss understood your question.

Comment: @VSZM me too :)

Comment: Typing 'cd -' again is good way to do@AndréKuhlmann

Answer (score 63):

The other answers are definitely complete in the direct answer sense.  `cd -` and `cd $OLDPWD` are definitely the main choices for this.  However, I often find that getting into a workflow with `pushd` and `popd` works better.

Long story short, if you are moving into a directory with the ultimate intent of coming back to where you started, use `pushd`/`popd`.

### Extended example

The major difference is easily shown by an example.

```
$ cd dir1
$ pushd dir2
```

At this point, you have a directory stack that is `dir2, dir1`.  Running `pushd` with no arguments will put you back in `dir1` with the stack now as `dir1, dir2`.  `popd` would do the same, but would leave you with an empty directory stack.  This is not much different than how you would have been with the `cd -` workflow.

However, now you can now change directories multiple times and get back to `dir1`.  For example,

```
$ cd dir1
$ pushd dir2
$ cd dir3
```

If you run `popd` at this point, you will go back to `dir1`.

Comment: You can also stack directories, so repeatedly use `pushd` and go back to previous folder while `popd`-ing.

Comment: Certainly.  I almost put a large example that included checking the stack with `dirs -v`, but the reality for me is that often the simple case is all I really use.  (Or, worse, I make a mistake when trying `push +2` or similar)  Also, I thought baby steps for getting someone to try the workflow.  :)

Comment: How do you `cd` to the top of the stack without popping?

Comment: Do you need to use `popd` at all? Could you not just `cd` and `pushd` everywhere? Are there any disadvantages to doing so?

Comment: @Prometheus, if just CD around you also don't need to push. The idea is to retrieve the position later with pop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193048/bin-sh-pushd-not-found

Answer (score 26):

You should use:

```
cd ~-
```

it does the same as `cd -` (from the currently accepted answer) without the annoying echo of the directory and is easier to type than `cd "$OLDPWD"` or `cd - > /dev/null`.

Comment: Redirecting the echo to null file ! It's genius !!

Comment: The echo shows the new directory not the previous one. And I would find it useful, so that I know where I am now, especially if I'm in a shell that only shows the current directory name (or nothing at all) on the prompt, and I'm too unbothered to change the prompt to show the full path. Of course, if your prompt already shows the full path, the echo would be redundant and annoying. In that case, I think you can try doing `alias -- -='cd "$OLDPWD"'` then using `-` (1 char) instead of `cd ~-` (5 char). `:)`

Comment: Source and explanation: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/330885/38213 Spoilers, - is an operand and ~'s are path aliases. So `cd ~-/..` works but `cd -/..` does not!

Comment: Why does this work? Where can I find the documentation? It’s not on the `--help`.

Answer (score 19):

```
$ cd -
```

will change to the previous working directory.

Answer (score 3):

You can "define a key" for `cd -` by editing your `~/.bashrc` file and including an alias for the command. For example you could add `cdc` to make it `cd -` which would provide you with a shorter way to get to the last directory by adding:

```
alias cdc='cd -'
```

This way you would simply type `cdc` and it would put you in your last working directory.

Comment: And confuse you to no end when you use a system where that alias isn't in place. It saves typing one character every once in a while. Why even bother?

Comment: "In terminal, **how can I define a key** to go to the previous directory"

I never get confused. Its just a shortcut, when you are on another system just use the long-hand way.

Comment: @Atari911 great question! here's the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200800 Here's what I did (bound F12): `bind '"\e[24~":"\C-k \C-ucd -\n"'` (or more preferably move it to `inputrc` file as mentioned in the answer).

Answer (score 1):

`cd ..` goes to the precedent folder in the folder's tree.
`cd -` goes to the folder which it was before. This command didn't work on some distros (ubuntu 16.04), works in debian 9.

Answer (score 0):

I find the combination of [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) and [dirs](https://ss64.com/bash/dirs.html) to be powerful for quickly navigating to any previously visited directory. [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) helps me sift through my directory history as [dirs](https://ss64.com/bash/dirs.html) helps me list the directories on the directory stack.

I define the following alias called `ch` as follows:

```
alias ch="cd \$(dirs -pl | fzf)"
```

Now, if you type `ch` in the terminal you will see the following, and you can select the directory you want to move into.
[image]