# Difference between "cd -" and "cd ~-"

Tags: bash, directory, cd-command, pushd

The Bash command

```
cd -
```

prints the previously used directory and changes to it.

On the other hand, the Bash command

```
cd ~-
```

directly changes to the previously used directory, without echoing anything.

Is that the only difference?  What is the use case for each of the commands?

Comment: I recommend you don't use any of this tricky stuff. This is your brain on `cd ~-`.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel, even if you don't (plan to) use tricky stuff, it's still useful to understand what's going on behind the scenes — understanding corner cases can get you out of a hole later on when trying to debug something different.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

There are two things at play here. First, the `-` alone is expanded to your previous directory. This is explained in the `cd` section of `man bash` (emphasis mine):

> An argument of `-` is converted to  $OLDPWD
>                 before  the directory change is attempted.  **If a non-empty directory name from CDPATH is used, or if `-` is the first
>   argument, and the directory change is successful, the absolute pathname of the new working directory is written to the 
>   standard output.**  The return value is true if the directory was successfully changed; false otherwise.

So, a simple `cd -` will move you back to your previous directory and print the directory's name out. The other command is documented in the "Tilde Expansion" section:

> If  the  tilde-prefix  is  a  `~+`, the value of the shell variable
>   PWD replaces the tilde-prefix.  If the tilde-prefix is a `~-`, the
>   value of the  shell variable OLDPWD, if it is set, is substituted. 
>   If the characters following the tilde in the tilde-prefix consist
>   of a  number  N,    optionally  prefixed  by  a  `+` or a `-`, the
>   tilde-prefix is replaced    with the corresponding element from the
>   directory stack, as it would be    displayed by the dirs builtin
>   invoked with the tilde-prefix as an argument.  If the characters
>   following the tilde in the  tilde-prefix  consist of a number
>   without a leading `+` or `-`, `+` is assumed.

This might be easier to understand with an example:

```
$ pwd
/home/terdon
$ cd ~/foo
$ pwd
/home/terdon/foo
$ cd /etc
$ pwd
/etc
$ echo ~        ## prints $HOME
/home/terdon
$ echo ~+       ## prints $PWD
/etc
$ echo ~-       ## prints $OLDPWD
/home/terdon/foo
```

So, in general, the `-` means "the previous directory". That's why `cd -` by itself will move you back to wherever you were.

The main difference is that `cd -` is specific to the `cd` builtin. If you try to `echo -` it will just print a `-`. The `~-` is part of the tilde expansion functionality and behaves similarly to a variable. That's why you can `echo ~-` and get something meaningful. You can also use it in `cd ~-` but you could just as well use it in any other command. For example `cp ~-/* .` which would be equivalent to `cp "$OLDPWD"/* .`

Comment: `set -x` to print the expanded command before executing it might be useful to illustrate the difference (or might just be unreadably noisy when you're not doing it yourself one step at a time).

Comment: @terdon today I learned.

Comment: In short... `cd ~-/..` works, `cd -/..` does not!

Comment: amazing!........

Answer (score 18):

`~-` is subject to tilde expansion (see man bash), so what `cd` sees is the previous directory name directly. `-` is not expanded by the shell, `cd` sees it directly, and behaves as documented:

> An argument of - is equivalent to $OLDPWD.  If a non-empty directory name from CDPATH is used, or if -  is  the  first  argument,  and  the directory  change  is  successful, the absolute pathname of the new working directory is written to the standard output.

Answer (score 9):

TL;DR: `cd -` is built into `cd`, `~-` is a later extension of `~[name]`, not specific to `cd`.

[POSIX.1-2008 Shell & Utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) defines `cd -` as a special case that is *specific* for the [`cd` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html):

> When a `-` is used as the operand, this shall be equivalent to the command:
>
> `cd "$OLDPWD" && pwd`
>
> which changes to the previous working directory and then writes its name.

The `~-` extension will be expanded to `$OLDPWD` before any command is executed and can be passed as an argument for any command, not just `cd`.  It is a later extension in [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh) and [bash](/questions/tagged/bash).

The aforementioned POSIX.1-2008 Shell & Utilities standard also has [an elaborate explanation of Tilde Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01). The wording is very specific to allow for `~-` as undefined behaviour within the scope of the standard, where `~[name]` refers to `$HOME` if `[name]` is the empty string, or the home directory of user `name` if `name` is a valid user name.