# Can you conveniently rename a file without changing directory?

Tags: bash, rename

Is there a convenient way to rename a file (or dir) without redundantly repeating the path or directory-changing to it?

For example …

```
mv -some_flag db/migrations/abc_201911201243.php abc_20191101090000.php
```

… to rename the file without moving it out of that directory.

I looked into the man pages for `mv`, `rename` and `rsync` but didn't find anything, so I'm wondering if there is by chance a non-obvious trick to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use brace expansion:

```
mv -some_flag db/migrations/abc_201911{201243,01090000}.php
```

Comment: That's so cool! I learned something useful today. And I've taken the liberty of removing the `-some_flag` since in my question it was assumed to be part of the solution; but for this solution, it isn't.

Comment: @WoodrowShigeru: Well, including it was kind of needed, as it demonstrates nothing can be placed *between* the file names.

Answer (score -1):

I guess I already found a suitable solution: you change the directory [and then return](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/330885/278372).

```
cd db/migrations/ && mv abc_201911201243.php abc_20191101090000.php && cd ~-
```

Comment: or, if you find it simpler, a subshell: `(cd db/migrations/ && mv abc_201911201243.php abc_20191101090000.php)`

Comment: note, if `mv` aborts, shell won't return you to original directory

Comment: But after you type "cd db/migrations/ && mv abc_", and you press TAB, nothing happens. The brace expansion is a bit both - nice idea. For me, a `cd`, a tab completion and a corrected tab completion is as convenient as it can get. Depends on the length of the names also, and copy pasting them or not (hey it is allowed...sometimes ;)