# Shortcut in mv command to rename file without changing its directory

Tags: rename, mv

I would like to be able to do this

`mv /long/path/to/file/old.txt /long/path/to/file/new.txt`

without typing the directory twice. I imagine something like

`rename /long/path/to/file/old.txt new.txt`

Is this possible?

Comment: See recent (very similar) question [Can you conveniently rename a file without changing directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553136/can-you-conveniently-rename-a-file-without-changing-directory)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with brace expansion:

```
mv /long/path/to/file/{old,new}.txt
```

Comment: The fun thing about brace expansion is that it's generative, rather than matching,  so you can generate paths that don't exist yet.